# Manage google dataproc preemptible-workers persistent disk size

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using jupyter on a cluster created using google dataproc and it is working very well.

I tried to change cluster "**size**" (machine type, boot disk size, number of workers, ...) to fit to my needs, and it is working pretty well.

The main issue is I don't get how to change the persistent disk size for preemptible-workers.

I'm using this command:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create jupyter --project <my_project>   --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh --num-preemptible-workers 0 --master-boot-disk-size 25 --worker-boot-disk-size 10  --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 --worker-boot-disk-size 10
```

I hoped the "`--worker-boot-disk-size 10`" option would have been applied also to preemptible ones, but it did not.

So, is there any way to change preemptible-workers boot disk size?

Furthermore, will Google charge me for the preemtible worker persistent disk usage?

Answer (score 1):

The beta dataproc gcloud channel offers --preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size which sounds like the thing you want.

For example:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create ... --preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size 500GB
```

Announced here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/release-notes/service#july_1_2016

As of september_16_2016 release, --preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size can be used without creating any preemptible VMs:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes/service#september_16_2016

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention: 
you can use "--preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size" only while you are creating your cluster.
If you create a cluster and then you use

```
gcloud dataproc clusters update  jupyter --project <my_project> --num-preemptible-workers 50
```

new preemptible istances will have 100GB of persistent disk size.
If you try with:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters update  jupyter --project <my_project> --num-preemptible-workers 50 --preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size 10
```

or

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters update  jupyter --project <my_project> --num-preemptible-workers 50 --preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size 10
```

it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. Would you be able to share your use case where default 100GB is not enough? If you can, kindly email dataproc-feedback@google.com

Comment: 100 GB was more than I needed. My aim was to reduce the disk dimension to reduce costs.

Comment: Hi, this is now fixed. You can specify --num-preemptible-workers when creating a cluster without creating any preemptible VMs.
See: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes/service#september_16_2016